# Make RabbitMQ wait for message consumption, and then raise exception

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there any way I can achieve this:

- Write a message to a queue
- Block the producer process until there is a consumer on the other side
- If there is no consumer after 10 seconds, raise an exception
- If there is a consumer, unblock the producer process
- **When the 10sec timeout is reached and an exception is raised on the producer side, the message should be kept in the queue, so that a consumer can consume it later**

I want to be able to notify a consumer in an asynchrone way. 
Until now I'm sending a message. I want to know if there is an immediate consumer, but if there is not, the message should still be on the queue. It doesn't seem to be the behavior of the "immediate" amqp thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, unfortunately there isn't an elegant solution.

From the RabbitMQ documentation the "immediate" flag works like this:

> This flag tells the server how to react if the message cannot be routed to a queue consumer immediately. If this flag is set, the server will return an undeliverable message with a Return method. If this flag is zero, the server will queue the message, but with no guarantee that it will ever be consumed.

You could solve your problem in part using the immediate flag, I'm thinking something like this:

- When the producer is ready to queue a message it fires it off with the immediate flag set
- If the message is returned then start a timer and keep retrying for 10 seconds with the immediate flag set
- If after 10 seconds of trying it has still failed to be picked up, then publish it with the immediate flag set to false (so that your consumer will pick it up when the consumer comes online)

Comment: for records, the immediate flag does not exist anymore. my connector version: amqp-client-5.1.2